# Drawing an ellipse with mid point algorithm based on fourth quadran

Tags: algorithm

I have to draw an ellipse starting with the fourth quadran, based on the mid point algorithm. I have a code that draw it from the first, but I don't understand how to modify the formula for making it works with the fourth.
I was thinking about simply invert the Y axis, but this is not allowed by my teacher (too easy). :/

```
void ellipseMedianMiniProjet(MyGrillePixels & g, int xC, int yC, int a, int b){
// Quatrième quadrant
int x=0, y=b, d, deltaE, deltaSE;
int b2=b*b, a2=a*a;

d = 4*b2 - a2*(1-4*b);

g.allumerPixel(0+xC,b+yC,126,20,251); // Allumage du promier et de ses 3 symétriques
g.allumerPixel(0+xC,-b+yC,126,20,251);
g.allumerPixel(a+xC,0+yC,126,20,251);
g.allumerPixel(-a+xC,0+yC,126,20,251);

while(2*b2*(x+1) < a2*(2*y-1)){ // 1ère région
    if(d<0){ // Mouvement vers l'est
        d+=b2*(8*x+12);
        x++;
    }else{ // Mouvement vers Sud Est
        d+= b2*(8*x+12)+8*a2*(1-y);
        x++; y--;
    }

    g.allumerPixel(x+xC,y+yC,126,20,251);
    //g.allumerPixel(-x+xC,y+yC,126,20,251);
    //g.allumerPixel(-x+xC,-y+yC,126,20,251);
    //g.allumerPixel(x+xC,-y+yC,126,20,251);
}

// 2ème région
d = b2*(2*x+1)*(2*x+1) + 4*a2*(y-1)*(y-1)-4*a2*b2;

while(y>0){
    if(d<0){ // Mvt SE
        d+= a2*(12-8*y)+b2*(8*x+8);
        x++;
        y--;
    }else{ // Mvt S
        d+= a2*(12-8*y);
        y--;
    }
    g.allumerPixel(x+xC,y+yC,126,20,251);
    //g.allumerPixel(-x+xC,y+yC,126,20,251);
    //g.allumerPixel(-x+xC,-y+yC,126,20,251);
    //g.allumerPixel(x+xC,-y+yC,126,20,251);
}

while(x<a){
    g.allumerPixel(x+xC,y+yC,126,20,251);
    //g.allumerPixel(-x+xC,y+yC,126,20,251);
    //g.allumerPixel(-x+xC,-y+yC,126,20,251);
    //g.allumerPixel(x+xC,-y+yC,126,20,251);
    x++;
}
```

}

The code is in French. a represent **x** radius, and b **y** radius.
How do I change the algo to start from 4th quadran?

Thx in advance for help.

Comment: You're trying to implement a Bresenham's algorithm, right?

Comment: Yes it is right.

Comment: OK, but I don't get something... You _DID_ do a symetry for 1st point, and clearly planned to do the same for other points. Can you modify your question to explain which quadrant is which (seems that 1st is NE one, for the others it's...?), and the assignment's text, with formula, to get all hypothesis you have and only them? If you use machine-translation for that, please also put original French text...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, I used this algorithm years ago for graphics under DOS. It was very fast for the time, it should still be.

I assume that "allumerPixel" takes, as parameters, `X` and `Y` coordinates, then a `(R,G,B)` triplet. You should pass it as parameter to your function, as a structure and/or a tuple, it would be more convenient

Globally, the algorithm rely on the following formula:

> x²/Rx² + y²/Ry² = 1

I let you do the details for the maths, but it's easy to both get `y` (`y=sqrt(Ry²*(1-(x²/Rx²)))`) and, knowing the function `y(x)`, to get the delta when you search for `y(x+1)`.

Also, to avoid costly square roots, it's easier to work with squares instead for the equation.
Obviously, the plots are done on correct values, only the deviation test is done with squares: knowing that `x` is positive, it's the same to test `x>sqrt(a)` or `x²>a`.

I couldn't test the code since I don't have your `MyGrillePixels` object, and I don't have time to set up a drawable test program for now. But it should work.

If you need to fill the ellipse, it's possible within the `while` block. I left comments to show where.

```cpp
// Rx and Ry must be positive, in fact, code should enforce this precondition.
void Ellipse ( MyGrillePixels& g, int X, int Y, int Rx, int Ry )
{
  int Yr = -Ry ;               // TAKE CARE: Using a negative number here is the key for below tests AND the direction of the "for" loop, don't change it.
  long long int Acc = -1 ;     // Accumulator
  long long int Rx2 = Rx*Rx ;  // Used to get (Rx/Ry)²
  long long int Ry2 = Ry*Ry ;  // Can also use a double for precision, but it defeats Bresenham's algorithm to use only integers.

  // Parse the first quadrant (trigonometric, so top-right quadrant).
  for (int Xr = 0 ; Xr<=Rx ; Xr++) {
    // Plot horizontally, use the 4 possible symmetries.
    g.allumerPixel(X+Xr,Y+Yr,126,20,251);
    g.allumerPixel(X-Xr,Y+Yr,126,20,251);
    g.allumerPixel(X+Xr,Y-Yr,126,20,251);
    g.allumerPixel(X-Xr,Y-Yr,126,20,251);
    // Add to accumulator only the delta part
    Acc += 2*Xr + 1 ;
    // Test for a vertical "line", otherwise ellipse may not be complete.
    // Do that either until we finished ellipse (Yr<0), or if we deviate too much (Acc>0).
    while ((Acc>0) && (Yr<0)) {
      // Start to plot vertically. Often reduced to one only pixel.
      Yr++;
      // Here: can draw an horizontal line from (X-Xr+1) to (X+Xr-1), line (Y+Yr).
      // Color can be different from color used for border.
      g.allumerPixel(X+Xr,Y+Yr,126,20,251);
      g.allumerPixel(X-Xr,Y+Yr,126,20,251);
      // Here: can draw an horizontal line from (X-Xr+1) to (X+Xr-1), line (Y-Yr).
      g.allumerPixel(X+Xr,Y-Yr,126,20,251);
      g.allumerPixel(X-Xr,Y-Yr,126,20,251);
      // Compute deviation.
      Acc += (Rx2*(2*Yr + 1)) / Ry2 ;
    }
  }
}
```

*Also, a little advice, avoid franglais in your code: use full French, or full English, but avoid mixing the two... Like "ecrireData" or "readDonnees". It's ugly, and anyway you can't use accents for French words so it can be also quite difficult to read sometimes. I'm used to kill every franglais I found in my company's code, because it's always a real pain for everyone. Stick to English, more readable...*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but I'm very sorry, I have to stick to my teacher's algorithm. He want us just modify the equation and conditions to make it work. :/

Comment: @SofianeLasri I'm quite sure that you didn't understood something in your teacher's assignment: modifying the equation to get the other quadrants is just dense stupid - that's maths, not computing. The base principle of Bresenham's algorithms is to use symmetries, not to compute a parametric/euclidian equation - it's designed to AVOID using floating-point numbers and mathematical operations in favor of integer operations and a "change direction" criteria. And simply speaking about quadrants implies a symmetry, otherwise a parametric equation would be simpler (and more accurate)...

Comment: Yes I know and I'm according with you but, my teacher explicitely told me to not the symetry to start creating the right bottom quadrant. Thank you anyway for taking the time to help me.